# Maven: Failure to find com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:jar

Tags: maven, google-play-services

we are trying to use [com.google.android.gms:play-services-location](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-location/17.0.0) but unable to get our project to build. The problem seems to be that maven tries to download a JAR whereas this artifact exists as a AAR file. Here is our pom.xml

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
      <artifactId>play-services-location</artifactId>
      <version>17.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
...
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>google-local-repo</id>
      <name>Google Maven Repo</name>
      <url>file:///Users/sjain68/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>google-remote-repo</id>
      <name>Google Maven Repo</name>
      <url>https://maven.google.com</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

No matter how hard we try, we get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project android: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.google.zxing:android:apk:4.7.10: Failure to find com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:jar:17.0.0 in https://maven.google.com was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of google-remote-repo has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

and it is true. The JAR does not exist. Its a AAR file. How can we tell maven to look for AAR file instead of JAR?

```
$ wget https://maven.google.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/17.0.0/play-services-location-17.0.0.aar
--2019-06-27 13:19:49--  https://maven.google.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/17.0.0/play-services-location-17.0.0.aar
Resolving maven.google.com (maven.google.com)... 172.217.3.195
Connecting to maven.google.com (maven.google.com)|172.217.3.195|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/17.0.0/play-services-location-17.0.0.aar [following]
--2019-06-27 13:19:50--  https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/17.0.0/play-services-location-17.0.0.aar
Resolving dl.google.com (dl.google.com)... 216.58.193.78
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|216.58.193.78|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 128878 (126K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘play-services-location-17.0.0.aar’

play-services-location-17.0.0.aar 100%[==========================================================>] 125.86K  --.-KB/s    in 0.03s

2019-06-27 13:19:50 (4.81 MB/s) - ‘play-services-location-17.0.0.aar’ saved [128878/128878]
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it to work using `<type>aar</type>`:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
      <artifactId>play-services-location</artifactId>
      <version>17.0.0</version>
      <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>
```